# What is the difference between fontawesome angular package and standard npm package and simple sass

Tags: angular, npm, sass, font-awesome, angular-fontawesome

I've a new angular cli(8+) project with sass(SCSS). I checked Fontawesome docs and have found multiple ways of hosting fontawesome icons ([npm package install](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/setup/using-package-managers), [angular package](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/using-with/angular) or [simple scss](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/using-with/sass)).

I want to know what are the differences between them? Which is the recommended way for an Angular CLI project having sass.

Answer (score 1):

When you install Fontawesome via the npm package manager it comes already with all the Scss files. So, there is not a choice between "npm package install" and "simple Scss". 
The question here is more: *Using the package manager or hosting yourself only the Scss files you will need* in your project inside the assets folder for example? 
Choosing that last option you won't be able to easily update the library version with npm.

**EDIT:** With this CSS/SCSS approach you'll always load all icons (a font file, which is a huge especially for FontAwesome Pro)

The angular package it's quite another subject. It's a new official package of FontAwesome. Instead of importing inside your project the Scss files, you can directly use FontAwesome Angular component.

**EDIT:** This package uses SVG icons instead and will use Angular CLI infrastructure to remove all unused icons from your final bundle.

**The simpler:**

- Install npm package or host only the CSS minified files you need,
- add a link to the file(s) location in your angular.cli file

You will be able to use the Fontawesome classes (like *.fab .fa-twitter*) in all your Html files.

**Sccs import :**

If you want to personalize your classes with Fontawesome mixins, you can import Scss files inside any Scss files of your project.

A use case:  a *.user-button* class that extends a *.fa-icon* properties and contains a Fontawesome user icon.

**Angular package :**

You will never have to deal with FontAwesome classes, but **only** import the module inside your app.module.ts and use FontAwesome icons as specifics component.

Comment: I guess one important difference which you should mention is that with CSS/SCSS approach you'll always load all icons (a font file, which is a huge especially for FontAwesome Pro). If you use `angular-fontawesome` package it uses SVG icons instead and will use Angular CLI infrastructure to remove all unused icons from your final bundle. [ref 1](https://github.com/FortAwesome/angular-fontawesome/blob/d3f83a57b6adaa8991704b5d8caa1361722bd758/docs/usage.md#methodologies) and [ref 2](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/advanced/svg-javascript-core#comparing).

Comment: Some icons have animations... if I only integrate the scss files, will those animation icons work out of the box?

Comment: can you update your answer with the comments of @YaroslavAdmin . Then I'd except your answer as it will be complete then ...